# Filtering an array with a predicate, limit results?

Tags: ios, arrays, nsarray, nspredicate, array-filter

I am filtering an array that can have many objects with a predicate. I would like to limit the results returned for performance reasons. The array is not sorted, so once the limit is hit, I would like the search to stop.

Is this possible? I am not sure if by means of predicate directive or otherwise.

Comment: Are you actually hitting a performance problem with in-memory data filtering?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist My filtering is computationally heavy, so going though many objects is costly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use this combination of `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest` and `objectsAtIndexes`:

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
NSUInteger limit = ...;
NSIndexSet *set = [myArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    BOOL pass = ... // check if object passes test;
    if (pass) {
        count++;
        if (count >= limit)
            *stop = YES;  // stops further processing of the array
    }
    return pass;
}];

NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray objectsAtIndexes:set];
```

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution, thanks. I can use `evaluateWithObject:` to test the objects. I would prefer a more elegant method, but if nothing else is there, I will use the `*PassingTest:` methods.